# Passing an interface to another interface method

Tags: php, oop, covariance, contravariance, php-7.4

I need to implement an event-listener model in OOP. Now I have `EventInterface` and `ListenerInterface`. But I want to pass the event to a listener, as:

```
interface ListenerInterface {
  public function listen(EventInterface $event);
}
```

But I can't do that even if the `Event` I passed to the Listener implements `EventInterface`. What should I do then? I want to make it abstract for simple usage.

Screenshot from PhpStorm:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to do that. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: Give it the interface name there too. As long as the object you pass in implements that interface, you'll be fine.

Comment: userLoggedInEvent should implement ListenerInterface, that is what the message says, as long as it not logic , so you should check yout logic agian

Comment: The code in your screenshot does not match the code in the interface show. In the code you show, the interface only declares the method `listen()`, but in your screenshot it's complaining about the signature of the method `__construct()`. Please, add the appropriate code for this example (the actual interface and implementing class) **as code**, not screenshot, so I can give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, the question was closed, but it would be great if you could you update it with the correct code anyway. Additionally, feedback on the answer below would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SendUserNotificationListener` **does not** comply with the contract set forth by `ListenerInterface`.

The error is helpfully telling you this. If you try to run this code, you'll get a fatal error and your script will crash.

If you have a couple of interfaces like this:

```
interface ParentInterface {
    public function foo();
}

interface ChildInterface extends ParentInterface {
    public function bar();
}

interface AnotherChildInterface extends ParentInterface {
    public function baz();
}

interface OriginalHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ParentInterface $a): string;
}
```

Any class that implements `OriginalHandlerInterfce` needs to follow it **exactly**

E.g.

```
class OriginalImplementor implements OriginalHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ParentInterface $a) : string
    {
        return class_name($a);
    }
}
```

If you try to make the implementation use *covariance* on the **parameter**, it will fail, since the implementation will not follow the interface. E.g.

```
class WrongOriginalImplementor implements OriginalHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ChildInterface $a) : string
    {
        return class_name($a);
    }
}
```

The logic for this is simple and sound. If someone is using a class you made that declares that implements `OriginalHandlerInterface`, that user should not need to look at your implementation at all, they need only to look at the interfaces.

If the original interface declares that `handle()` expects a `ParentInterface` object, it means I can pass it objects from classes that implement `ParentInterface`, but objects from classes that implement `ChildInterface` or `AnotherChildInterface` would also be valid.

On the other hand, if your implementation were able to say `handle(ChildInterface $a)`, then the user would have their expectations betrayed, since they would not be able to pass `handle()` an object from a class that implements `AnotherChildInterface`, despite being valid according to the `OriginalHandlerInterface`.

On the other hand, if you had this interface:

```
interface AnotherHandlerInterface
{ 
    public function handle(ChildInterface $a): string;
}
```

Your implementations could use *contravariance* on the `handle()` parameter. They could specify a *less restrictive parameter type*. E.g.:

```
class ContravariantImplementor implements AnotherHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(ParentInterface $a): string {
        return class_name($a);
    }
}
```

This implementation, despite not following to the dot, **is valid**. Again, if you think about it the same logic applies: a consumer for your class could look at `AnotherHandlerInterface` and see that `handle()` expects a `ChildInterface`. So they would never be tripped by your implementation if the follow the original contract.

Your implementation is less restrictive, and accepts objects that the original interface wouldn't, but that's fine because the rules for covariance and contravariance allow it.

Note that covariance and contravariance support is quite new in PHP, [and has been added only in PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php).

You can see the above code working [here](https://3v4l.org/sZ9XB) (including the error)